# Check in MSBuild script that MS Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 is installed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

In MS Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 they fixed several issues thereby our workarounds should be removed (incompatible with Update 3 but work in Update 2). If I just remove them, then developers that do not have Update 3 will see confusing build errors. I want to add into **MSBuild** script **a check that Update 3 is installed**. If it is not installed, then show the message that project requires it. I know there it property `$(VisualStudioVersion)` that tells visual studio version. The question is how to get Update number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the following Registry key using MsBuild:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\devenv\UpdateVersion
```

When update 3 is installed it should read at least:

```
14.0.25420
```

You can easily read registry values from MsBuild using:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioUpdateVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioUpdateVersion)' == '' ">
        $(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\devenv@UpdateVersion)
    </VisualStudioUpdateVersion>
    <VisualStudioUpdateVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioUpdateVersion)' == '' ">
        $(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0\devenv@UpdateVersion)
    </VisualStudioUpdateVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```